# How to set single parameter required in a parameter group with Swagger Block on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

I use `swagger-blocks` gem on a Rails app.

From the official README, it's possible to set special parameter required true or false:

https://github.com/fotinakis/swagger-blocks/blob/master/README.md

```
parameter do
  key :name, :id
  key :in, :path
  key :description, 'ID of pet to fetch'
  key :required, true
  key :type, :integer
  key :format, :int64
end
```

But if I need to let one of two parameters(either one is ok) be required as:

```
parameter do
  key :name, :id
  key :in, :path
  key :description, 'ID of pet to fetch'
  key :required, true
  key :type, :integer
  key :format, :int64
end

parameter do
  key :name, :user_id
  key :in, :path
  key :description, 'User ID of pet to fetch'
  key :required, true
  key :type, :integer
  key :format, :int64
end
```

How to do?

Comment: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256

Comment: Can you clarify how the actual endpoint is supposed to look like? Is it like a) `/pets/{user_id}/{id}` with 2 params; or b) `/pets/{id}` where `id` can be either pet ID or user ID?